# Android Studio 'findViewById' no longer working

Tags: android, kotlin

I am very new to Android/Kotlin. I have already created some programs and am making good progress.
But since today I have the problem that I can't get an '**findViewById**' running even in the standard 'Hello World' program (Empty Activity).

I have only added the line **android:id="@+id/myText"** in the XML.

And in MainActivity.kt the line **var myTxt = findViewById(android.R.id.myText)**.

But I get the error message Unresolved reference: 'myText'
The text 'myText' is red.

The usual attempts: Clear Cache, new project, ... I have already tried. The behavior is always the same.
In older projects 'findViewById' is working fine. But I find no difference in Import or settings between working and non working projects.

All in Android Studio 4.1.1

I am grateful for any help
Jan

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
package com.example.myhelloworld

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var myTxt = findViewById<TextView>(android.R.id.myText)

    }
}
```

Comment: For me it still works. Perhaps something else is the cause

Comment: remove "android." `var myTxt = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.myText)`

Comment: You will have to remove the `android` part from the `android.R.id.myText` and input your own project's R class in.

Answer (score 0):

`android.R.id.something` is only used for android's own internal resources. You should remove that and it will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin you dont need to set `findViewById` instead you can just call the `TextView` name like this: `myText.setText(userNameWithMsg)`

Comment: This is only true when you use a special library. I talk about the standard which is trained in each textbook.

Comment: @Janus That is NOT true, findViewById is trained by no modern book today, because it SUCKS

Answer (score 0):

**android.** was the problem! I removed it and all is fine again.

Thank you all! Must be a kind of copy paste error ;-))

Now I can go on .....

Great forum!
Thanks a lot
Jan